# toggle all divs except a div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm getting trouble to hide divs inside a div. I have the follwing html http://jsfiddle.net/CaK4r/
I want to hide all the divs and their childrens inside the container except div1 and its childrens with jQuery

Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#container > :not(#div1)')​​​​​​.hide();​
```

Note that if you hide a parent container all its children are also hidden so there is no need to hide them explicitly.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/CaK4r/2/

Comment: appearently i have something wrong. It hides also div1. Does it affect if the container is also inside three other divs?

Comment: If if works in jsfiddle then it should work fine if the markup structure is same.

Comment: When i look into the markup with IE I see the follwing : "<div id="left-panel-content><div class="ui-panel-content-text>" and then childs. <div class="ui-panel-content-text> it's added automatically, i don't have it anywhere in my code. The childs are created dynamically from code behind. On my asp.net markup I have the following: 
<div id="left-panel-content">
  <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litText"></asp:Literal>              </div>. From code-behind litText.Value = <mydivs> ;

Answer (score 0):

```
$("document").ready(function(){
       $("div").not("#div1").hide();           
});​
```

something like this should work. look at jquery .not